# Alfresco Login Issue

Tags: authentication, alfresco-share

I have installed Alfresco version 4.2.e community. After starting server I am able to login to Alfresco repository. But as I try to execute http://localhost:9090/share, I get below exception..

```
2015-02-21 18:26:26,897  INFO  [web.site.EditionInterceptor] [http-apr-8585-exec-8] Successfully retrieved license information from Alfresco.
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.alfresco.web.extensibility.SlingshotEvaluatorUtil.getPageId(Lorg/springframework/extensions/surf/RequestContext;)Ljava/lang/String;

        at org.alfresco.web.extensibility.SlingshotPageComponentElementEvaluator.evaluate(SlingshotPageComponentElementEvaluator.java:76)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.extensibility.impl.DefaultSubComponentEvaluation.evaluate(DefaultSubComponentEvaluation.java:145)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.types.SubComponent.determineURI(SubComponent.java:348)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.RenderService.renderSubComponent(RenderService.java:488)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.RenderService.processComponent(RenderService.java:419)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.RenderService.renderComponent(RenderService.java:942)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.bean.TemplateInstanceRenderer.header(TemplateInstanceRenderer.java:108)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.RenderService.renderTemplateHeaderAsString(RenderService.java:1142)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ProcessorModelHelper.populateTemplateModel(ProcessorModelHelper.java:663)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebTemplateProcessor.executeBody(WebTemplateProcessor.java:369)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.AbstractProcessor.execute(AbstractProcessor.java:57)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.RenderService.processTemplate(RenderService.java:721)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.bean.TemplateInstanceRenderer.body(TemplateInstanceRenderer.java:140)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.AbstractRenderer.render(AbstractRenderer.java:77)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.bean.PageRenderer.body(PageRenderer.java:85)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.AbstractRenderer.render(AbstractRenderer.java:77)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.RenderService.renderPage(RenderService.java:762)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.mvc.PageView.dispatchPage(PageView.java:411)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.mvc.PageView.renderView(PageView.java:250)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.mvc.AbstractWebFrameworkView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractWebFrameworkView.java:316)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.alfresco.web.site.servlet.MTAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(MTAuthenticationFilter.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.alfresco.web.site.servlet.SecurityHeadersFilter.doFilter(SecurityHeadersFilter.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.alfresco.web.site.servlet.CSRFFilter.doFilter(CSRFFilter.java:320)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.alfresco.web.site.servlet.SSOAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(SSOAuthenticationFilter.java:307)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
2015-02-21 18:26:30,273  ERROR [alfresco.web.site] [http-apr-8585-exec-8] org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exce
ption is java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.alfresco.web.extensibility.SlingshotEvaluatorUtil.getPageId(Lorg/springframework/extensions/surf/Reque
stContext;)Ljava/lang/String;
 java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.alfresco.web.extensibility.SlingshotEvaluatorUtil.getPageId(Lorg/springframework/extensions/surf/RequestContex
t;)Ljava/lang/String;
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.mvc.AbstractWebFrameworkView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractWebFrameworkView.java:324)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.alfresco.web.site.servlet.MTAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(MTAuthenticationFilter.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.alfresco.web.site.servlet.SecurityHeadersFilter.doFilter(SecurityHeadersFilter.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.alfresco.web.site.servlet.CSRFFilter.doFilter(CSRFFilter.java:320)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.alfresco.web.site.servlet.SSOAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(SSOAuthenticationFilter.java:307)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.alfresco.web.extensibility.SlingshotEvaluatorUtil.getPageId(Lorg/springframework/extensions/surf/RequestContext;)Ljava/la
ng/String;
        at org.alfresco.web.extensibility.SlingshotPageComponentElementEvaluator.evaluate(SlingshotPageComponentElementEvaluator.java:76)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.extensibility.impl.DefaultSubComponentEvaluation.evaluate(DefaultSubComponentEvaluation.java:145)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.types.SubComponent.determineURI(SubComponent.java:348)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.RenderService.renderSubComponent(RenderService.java:488)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.RenderService.processComponent(RenderService.java:419)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.RenderService.renderComponent(RenderService.java:942)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.bean.TemplateInstanceRenderer.header(TemplateInstanceRenderer.java:108)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.RenderService.renderTemplateHeaderAsString(RenderService.java:1142)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ProcessorModelHelper.populateTemplateModel(ProcessorModelHelper.java:663)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebTemplateProcessor.executeBody(WebTemplateProcessor.java:369)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.AbstractProcessor.execute(AbstractProcessor.java:57)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.RenderService.processTemplate(RenderService.java:721)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.bean.TemplateInstanceRenderer.body(TemplateInstanceRenderer.java:140)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.AbstractRenderer.render(AbstractRenderer.java:77)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.bean.PageRenderer.body(PageRenderer.java:85)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.AbstractRenderer.render(AbstractRenderer.java:77)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.render.RenderService.renderPage(RenderService.java:762)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.mvc.PageView.dispatchPage(PageView.java:411)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.mvc.PageView.renderView(PageView.java:250)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.mvc.AbstractWebFrameworkView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractWebFrameworkView.java:316)
        ... 36 more
```

Any idea what is the reason I am getting these error ?

Let me know your suggestions.

Regards.

Comment: How did you install Alfresco? Did you use the installer? On which environment? As default port Alfresco uses 8080 and so does share. If it is not a trouble for you try installing newer Alfresco community 4.2.f version.

Comment: yes, i used Alfresco installer for windows 64 bit, i was able to execute Alfresco repository url http://localhost:8080/alfresco, but this issue was coming for Alfresco share (http://localhost:8080/share), i tried reinstalling alfresco on different port also, but I got same error.

Comment: Have you tried with version 4.2.f? I suppose you're administrator on the machine you're installing on, aren't you?

Comment: yes, i tried with 4.2.f and it working fine. Thanks.